# How to make com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText to textview?

Tags: android, native-android

```
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16sp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/blue">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand_bold"
                        android:hint="Full Name"
                        android:textColor="@color/blue"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/blue" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I used this for Edittext but I don't know how to use it for Textview

I want like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX5kd.png)

Comment: Are you trying to use material Textview? or are you trying to use this textinputlayout itself as TextView itself, like user can't enter any value in textinputedittext?

Answer (score 0):

```
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="false"
android:cursorVisible="false"
```

add this to EditText